# Typescript - export was not found

Tags: typescript

I have this Typescript file in module A:

```
// somefile.tsx
import { remAuto } from 'tidee-life-theme';
```

In module B, I have the index.js file export `remAuto`:

```
// index.js
import { remAuto } from './src/utils';
export default {
  remAuto,
};
```

However, when I build using Webpack I get this error:

> WARNING in ./src/components/somefile.tsx 50:20-27 "export 'remAuto'
> was not found in 'module-b'

`remAuto` is clearly being exported and this worked prior to me trying to convert parts of module A to Typescript. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be a non-default export

```
export {
  remAuto,
};
```

Otherwise you should import a default then destructure it

```
import tideelifetheme from 'tidee-life-theme';
const { remAuto } = tideelifetheme;
```

Why:

Because the

```
export default {
  remAuto,
};
```

is read as: "export an object with `remAuto` property assigned to `remAuto` value".

While

```
import { remAuto } from 'tidee-life-theme';
```

is read as "import a named import with `remAuto` identifier" (and you don't have one).

To summarise: named exports and exporting an object by default are not interchangeable.

Comment: Is this specific to Typescript, because it was all working fine before?

Comment: @JoeTidee it should not have worked in ES2015+ either, for the same reasons. if it worked - it means webpack (or some of its plugins) slightly forgiven you for your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had an import like this

```
import { CategoryLayoutDisplayTypesEnum,MobileSettingsService} from 'src/app/modules/sales-channels';
```

It turned out that I should change it like this!

```
import { CategoryLayoutDisplayTypesEnum } from 'src/app/modules/sales-channels/data';
import { MobileSettingsService } from 'src/app/modules/sales-channels/data-access/services';
```

Answer (score 0):

I also met this while *reexporting a type*:

```js
import { toast, ToastContent, ToastOptions, Id as ToastId } from 'react-toastify';
export { ToastId };
```

Typescript understands that no problem; but webpack complains:

> export 'Id' (reexported as 'ToastId') was not found in 'react-toastify' (possible exports: Bounce, Flip, Icons, Slide, ToastContainer, Zoom, collapseToast, cssTransition, toast, useToast, useToastContainer)

As the [second comment in webpack#7378](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/7378#issuecomment-392264102) kindly explained, this `Id` I'm importing is a TS **interface** i.e. a type. And types get erased when JS gets extracted from TS.

Hence, what helped in my case was to say `export type`:

```js
import { toast, ToastContent, ToastOptions, Id as ToastId } from 'react-toastify';

export type { ToastId };
```