# Converting JavaScript modules to TypeScript - problems with exporting / importing

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-modules

I am trying to convert a JavaScript project using modules to TypeScript but I am having problems with exporting and importing. The modules are part of a larger MVC project I have developed in Visual Studio.

Below, I have constructed a minimum working example to illustrate the problem. The original JavaScript version works fine. I have a module *test-module.js*

```
// TEST MODULE

class MyClassA {

    TestA() {

        console.log("MyClassA.TestA");
    }
}

class MyClassB {

    TestB() {

        console.log("MyClassB.TestB");
    }
}

export {
    MyClassA,
    MyClassB
};
```

which is imported by a test script *test-script.js*

```
// TEST SCRIPT

import {
    MyClassA,
    MyClassB
} from './test-module.js';

console.log("This is the test script.");

const myClassA = new MyClassA();
const myClassB = new MyClassB();

myClassA.TestA();
myClassB.TestB();
```

This gives the output

```
This is the test script.
MyClassA.TestA
MyClassB.TestB
```

as expected.

I then copy these to TypeScript files (no changes are needed) and compile these to JavaScript. I have installed the **Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild** package, version 4.8.2 via the NuGet package manager and have the following *tsconfig.json* file in my root folder:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "target": "ES5",
    "lib": [ "ES2015", "DOM" ],
    "outDir": "Scripts/MTR-client"
  },
  "include": [
    "TS-Scripts/**/*"
  ]
}
```

First, I compile the test module. This produces the following JavaScript:

```
"use strict";
// TEST MODULE
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.MyClassB = exports.MyClassA = void 0;
var MyClassA = /** @class */ (function () {
    function MyClassA() {
    }
    MyClassA.prototype.TestA = function () {
        console.log("MyClassA.TestA");
    };
    return MyClassA;
}());
exports.MyClassA = MyClassA;
var MyClassB = /** @class */ (function () {
    function MyClassB() {
    }
    MyClassB.prototype.TestB = function () {
        console.log("MyClassB.TestB");
    };
    return MyClassB;
}());
exports.MyClassB = MyClassB;
```

If I try using this with the original JavaScript, I get the error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './test-module.js' does not provide an export named 'MyClassA' (at test-script.js:4:5)
```

I then try compiling the test script to see if this fixes the problem. The compiled JavaScript is

```
"use strict";
// TEST SCRIPT
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var test_module_js_1 = require("./test-module.js");
console.log("This is the test script.");
var myClassA = new test_module_js_1.MyClassA();
var myClassB = new test_module_js_1.MyClassB();
myClassA.TestA();
myClassB.TestB();
```

Note that this uses `require`, which does not actually work in normal JavaScript! Trying to run the new code, I get

```
test-script.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    at test-script.js:3:23
```

which does not surprise me given the generated code. What does surprise me is that the TypeScript compiler has not created equivalent JavaScript. The output for the test script looks more like React.

I have seen issues relating to exporting / importing on Stack Overflow, such as
[typescript-export-was-not-found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68931003/typescript-export-was-not-found) but this seems to relate to the problem of mixing named and default exports / imports. My code uses named exports / imports in both cases and the original JavaScript works.

I am wondering if this is a problem with the way **Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild** is doing the compilation - maybe some setting I am missing?

I would greatly appreciate any insight that can be offered on this!

Comment: How are you running those (java)scripts, are you not using node.js?

Comment: You'll need to instruct the typescript compiler to output es6 modules, not commonjs modules. Given you used `class` syntax in your original javascript, you also will want to change your `lib` and `target` settings to at least ES6, if not higher.

Comment: Hi Bergi. Changed target and lib to "ES6" as you suggested. I am not using node.js - building with Visual Studio. However, whilst the output JavaScript files initially have the undefined references to 'exports', after building the project the generated files now have these stripped out and things seem to work. Also have class syntax back. Not quite sure what is going on!